# How many ways are there to distribute 62 indistinguishable white balls and 8 distinguishable numbered balls into 10 distinguishable boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

This is my attempt at the problem:

There are $\binom{10+62-1}{62}$ ways to put the 62 white balls into the 10 distinguishable boxes. I am not sure how count the number of ways to put 8 distinguishable numbered balls into 10 distinguishable boxes. If I did though, I would multiple it by $\binom{10+62-1}{62}$ and that would be my final answer.

The answer in the book is $\binom{10+62-1}{62} 10^8$. Where did the $10^8$ come from?

Comment: Each  distinguishable ball has $10$ choices, and they can be made independently .

Comment: @lulu Wow, such a slight modification to the way I was thinking about it but it makes total sense now. Thanks!